# ORA-01036: как исправить данную проблему?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

При выполнении запроса назад возвращает сообщение о том, что неверный тип данных.
Как это можно исправить?
Таблица SQL в Oracle SQL Database XE 11g release-2:

```
CREATE TABLE "questions"
("id" number not null,
"question" char(100));
```

Код программы, где все это выполняется:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

namespace DBKR
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        const string connectionString = "DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/xe;PASSWORD=12345;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=SYSTEM";

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            string b = richTextBox1.Text;

            using (OracleConnection ConnectionToOracle = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand
                {
                    CommandText = "INSERT INTO \"questions\" VALUES (@a, @b)",
                    Connection = ConnectionToOracle,
                };

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", OracleType.Int32).Value = a;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", OracleType.NVarChar).Value = b;
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
                ConnectionToOracle.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы декларируете `char(100)`, а сами передаете `OracleType.NVarChar` - это разные типы

Comment: Поправил в базе данных, ошибка никуда в итоге не ушла

Comment: А как вы поправили в базе? Nvarchar2 сделали?

Comment: да, в коде писал nvarchar2, но он выдает ошибку

Comment: Вообще у вас ошибка говорит, что не неверный тип данных, а неверное имя переменной

Comment: попробуйте имя таблицы без кавычек еще написать. Ради эксперимента

Comment: И еще совсем дурацкий совет. Попробуйте перенабрать имена колонок\параметров. Вдруг там где-то затесалась русская буковка

Comment: перепроверил уже все, уж даже не знаю куда рыть. Вчера попробовал убрать переменные, и написать типа +Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text)+ и там уже то запятой не хватает то еще какую-то ошибку

Comment: Вот как видоизменил это дело: ` private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 

            using (OracleConnection ConnectionToOracle = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO questions VALUES ('" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + ",'" + richTextBox1.Text + "')";
                cmd.Connection = ConnectionToOracle;
                ConnectionToOracle.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }`

Comment: А вы  попробуйте прямо указать значения - "insert into \"questions\" values (9999, 'test message')'"

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, обновленный код в тексте вопроса ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/829365/edit)). Постарайтесь избавиться от ссылок на элементы интерфейса (мы их не видим) и вставьте полное сообщение об ошибке вместе с типом ошибки и трассировкой стека.

Comment: Уберите кавычки у `questions` вместе со слешами, конечно. Переменные в запросе надо указывать через двоеточие `(:a,:b)`, а в параметрах без двоеточия `cmd.Parameters.Add("a"...`

Comment: теперь выдает ORA-00942, но таблица есть такая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже заметили, "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number" это неверное имя переменной либо их количество, а не тип.

Вообще, в Oracle **все числовые** (дробные/целые, без-/знаковые) типы данных соответствуют типу `Decimal` в .Net, а **все символьные** (+некоторые другие) соотв. `String` в .Net.
см. [сопоставление типов данных Oracle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yk72thhd(v=vs.100).aspx);

в вашем случае, для

```
CREATE TABLE "questions"
("id" number not null,
"question" char(100));
```

учитывая [перечисление OracleType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracletype(v=vs.110).aspx) вы могли бы написать так:

```
decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
string b = richTextBox1.Text;

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand
{
    CommandText = "INSERT INTO \"questions\" VALUES (:a, :b)",
    Connection = ConnectionToOracle,
};

cmd.Parameters.Add("a", OracleType.Number).Value = a;
cmd.Parameters.Add("b", OracleType.Char).Value = b;
```